# need help rehashing a hashtable in c

Tags: c, hashtable

I want to rehash a hashtable by allocating space for a new table, traverse the old table, and for each element, compute a
new hash value and then link it into the new table.  I have linked lists as entries into the hashtable thus the second for loop whilst traversing the old hashtable.  I also want to free the old table, but first get the elements into the new table correctly.

I need help, where am I going wrong in traversing the old table? Also can I just point the original ht to the newht at the end? I need to free the old table(prevtable) afterwards also, which I will figure out later.

```
typedef struct hashtable {
    htentry_ptr *table;         /*<< a pointer to the underlying table        */
    unsigned int size;          /*<< the current size of the underlying table */
    unsigned int num_entries;   /*<< the current number of entries            */
    float max_loadfactor;       /*<< the maximum load factor before the
                                 *   underlying table is resized              */
    unsigned short idx;         /*<< the index into the delta array           */
    unsigned int (*hash)(void *, unsigned int); /*<< a pointer to the hash function   */
    int (*cmp)(void *, void *);         /*<< a pointer to the comparison
                                         *   function                         */
} hashtable_t;
```

The rehash function looks like this

```
static void rehash(hashtab_ptr ht)
{
    hashtab_ptr prevtable;
    /* store reference to the old table */
    prevtable->table = ht->table;
    htentry_ptr p;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int newidx;
    printf("\nrehashing\n");
    ht->size = getsize(prevtable);
    printf("\nnew table size %d\n", ht->size);
    ht->table = calloc(ht->size , sizeof(htentry_t));
    for (i = 0; i < prevtable->size; i++) {
        for (p = prevtable->table[i]; p; p = p->next_ptr) {
            newidx = ht->hash(p->key, ht->size);
            if(ht->table[newidx]){
                htentry_ptr next;
                htentry_ptr prev = NULL;
                next = ht->table[newidx];
                printf("\ncollision adding to linked list\n");
                while (next) {
                    prev = next;
                    next = next->next_ptr;
                }
                prev->next_ptr = p;
                p->next_ptr = NULL;
            } else {
                ht->table[newidx] = p; 
                ht->table[newidx]->next_ptr = NULL;
                ht->num_entries++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

inserting into the hashtable.  When the table gets too dense the rehash function is called at the end of the insert.

```
int ht_insert(hashtab_ptr ht, void *key, void *value)
{
/* key is the id of the variable like num1 and value is number 
index = value 
*/

unsigned int N = ht->size;
unsigned int ne;
float current_loadfactor;
int k;
htentry_ptr p;
p = calloc(1,sizeof(htentry_t));
p->key = key;
p->value = value;
k = ht->hash(key, ht->size);
if(ht->table[k]){
    htentry_ptr next;
    htentry_ptr prev = NULL;
    /* theres already something in the index*/
    next = ht->table[k];
    printf("\ncollision adding to linked list");
    while (next) {
        prev = next;
        next = next->next_ptr;
    }
    ht->num_entries++;
    prev->next_ptr = p;
    p->next_ptr = NULL;
} else {
    ht->table[k] = p;
    ht->table[k]->next_ptr = NULL; 
    ht->num_entries++;
}
ne = ht->num_entries;
current_loadfactor = ne / N;
if (current_loadfactor > ht->max_loadfactor) {
    rehash(ht);
}
```

Comment: C is pass-by-value. Assigning to the function argument doesn't change the value of the corresponding object (if any) in the caller.

Comment: ... which means that the final assignment should be `*ht  = *newht;` (and th old one could be freed) . But that doesn't work (in the current form), so you either need a pointer-to-pointer, or return the new pointer to the caller. Do note that you don't *need* to reallocate the hashtable, only the ->table member is changed.

Comment: thank for the comments, I want  a pointer - to - pointer, so I want to point the old hashtable_ptr to the newht and then free the old one.  The ht I'm getting in is a global variable.

Comment: Pointer to pointer makes life easier (once you get used to it). [style] And jhiding a pointer behind a typedef is confusing. Please realize that in the struct, only the .array and .size need to be changed, the rest is copied from the old one.

Comment: basically as I understand I want to keep reference to the old table with prevtable(for freeing later). and then just create a new table and at the end point the argument ht to the  new one? Im not sure how to implement this with pointer - to - pointer.  I run rehash(ht) in the caller after an insert into the hashtable and the table gets too big.

Comment: After your mega-edit: `ht->size = getsize(prevtable);` new size will be the same as old size. 2) `printf("\nnew table size %u\n", ht->size);` see for your self 3) `ht->table = calloc(ht->size , sizeof(htentry_t));`: htentry_t is undefined (and the wrong type: the array is an array of pointers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is might be the solution, but im not 100% sure.

```
static void rehash(hashtab_ptr ht)
{
        unsigned int old_size, new_size;
        unsigned int newindex;
        unsigned int i;
        htentry_ptr q, p;
        htentry_ptr *new_table;
        old_size = ht->size;
        /*gets new size in prime table */
        new_size = getsize(ht);
        new_table = malloc(sizeof(htentry_t) * new_size);
        /* nullify the new table */
        for (i = 0; i < new_size; i++) {
            new_table[i] = NULL;
        }
        printf("\n*****rehashing******\n");
        ht->size = new_size; 
        printf("%s %d\n", "new size:", new_size);
        for (i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {
            p = ht->table[i];
            while (p) {
                q = p->next_ptr;
                newindex = ht->hash(p->key, new_size);
                /*
                temp = malloc(sizeof(htentry_t));
                temp->key = p->key;
                temp->value = p->value;
                temp->next_ptr = new_table[ht->hash(temp->key, next_size)];
                new_table[ht->hash(temp->key, next_size)] = temp;
                */
                if (new_table[newindex]) {
                    p->next_ptr = new_table[newindex];
                    new_table[newindex] = p;    
                } else {
                    new_table[newindex] = p;
                    new_table[newindex]->next_ptr = NULL;
                }
                p = q;
            }
        }

    free(ht->table);
    ht->table = new_table;  
}
```

Comment: Yest, that is the combination of my bullet#4 + the other answer. (and you can set p->next_pointer to NULL, after extracting q from it, but you'll still have to walk the new chain. now you are reversing the chains, which is not bad, but different.

Comment: And, the new table is exactly the same size as the old one (but scaled wrong: it is supposed to be an array of pointers, not entries [pro-hint: get rid of the typedefs; typedefs only exist to confuse you]

Comment: Oh, and you forgot to initialize new_table to NULLs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, forgot to add I have a function that calculates the new size: get_size() it actually gets the next prime size of the hash-table. Is it necessary to NULL all entries in new_table?  Yea this implementation pushes the old entries into the new table whereas the insert function inserts new entries at the back of the linked list.  Is this problematic?

Comment: ... which is completely useless. (because both cases are equal; at least after your 2nd edit)

Comment: true, thanks, I've run some tests and all seems fine, Am I missing any bugs?

Comment: Yes, you are allocating the wrong size. (which I already commented on). And prime-sized hashtables can be considered cargo-cult programming.

Comment: get_size() returns the next prime size in a delta array, basically calculating the next prime size  etc.  what resizing method would you recommend?

Comment: right, I see you times it by 2, Im doing prime sized hashtables to get a more even distribution of entries.

Comment: Which is complete nonsense. (prime-sizes can be used to hide the effects of very bad hash functions, though). As a test: use a random generator and create a histogram of `value % n`, for both prime and non-prime `n`. And: the resizing will of course depend of the (intended) usage and the expected dynamics.

Comment: then it doesnt really matter if it's prime or not? but ill use prime anyway, Im just reading up on this on other SO posts, I didnt make up the prime theory dont shoot the messenger. Im using a cyclic bit shift hash function which I understand is a pretty good one.

Answer (score 1):

> Also can I just point the original ht to the newht at the end?

No.

The pointer ht is a copy on the local function stack. Changing the value with `ht = newht;` just changes the copy.

The easiest solution would be to let your rehash() function return the pointer to the new hashtable.

```
static hashtab_ptr rehash(hashtab_ptr ht)
{
  [...]
  return newht;
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
current_ht = rehash(current_ht);
```

The second solution would be to change the prototype to pass a double pointer:

```
static void rehash(hashtab_ptr *ht)
{
  [...]
  *ht = newht;
}
```

This means that you need to change the use of ht everywhere in your rehash() function to reflect that it's a double pointer now.

The third solution would be to not create a new `hashtable_t`, but just create a new `htentry_ptr *table` area and update the values in `ht;` This would be my favorite solution in a code review.

> I need help, where am I going wrong in traversing the old table?

```
  while (next)
  {
    prev = next;
    next = next->next_ptr;
    newht->num_entries++;
  }
```

The `newht->num_entries++;` is at the wrong place. When you look for the end of the linked list, the elements that are already there don't increase the size of your hashtable. You can move the expression `newht->num_entries++;` out of both if/else - your table increases by one no matter if there is a collision or not.

Second, at the end of the linked list loop it will look like this:

```
prev = [last_element of linked list];
next = null;
prev->next_ptr = old_element;
```

But.. where does `old_element->next_ptr` point to? There is no guarantee that it is null.
So you need to add `p->next_ptr = NULL;` so that an element that wasn't formerly at the end of the collision and is now at the end of the collision properly ends the linked list.

The problem is you can't just do `p->next_ptr = NULL;` because then your loop thinks it's at the end. Your concept is screwed when a linked list element in the middle of the linked list gets reassigned to a new index in the new hashtable. The element can't have the correct value for the old and the new table in next_ptr at the same time.

So, there are two solutions:
a) Go backwards through your collision list, but as this is a single linked list as it seems, this is a very painful process of putting elements on a stack.
b) Rehash the table by creating new elements instead of trying to reuse the old elements.

**EDIT:**

Okay, with the insert function, the rehash function can look like this (quick & dirty):

```
static hashtab_ptr rehash(hashtab_ptr ht)
{
    hashtab_ptr prevtable = ht;
    hashtab_ptr newht;
    htentry_ptr p;
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int newidx;

    printf("\nrehashing");

    newht->idx  = prevtable->idx + 1;
    newht->size = getsize(prevtable);
    newht->num_entries = 0;
    newht->hash = prevtable->hash;
    newht->cmp  = prevtable->cmp;

    newht->max_loadfactor = prevtable->max_loadfactor;

    newht->table = calloc(newht->size , sizeof(htentry_t));

    for (i = 0; i < ht->size; i++) {
      for (p = ht->table[i]; p; p = p->next_ptr) {
        ht_insert(newht, p->key, p->value);
    }

    return newht;
   }
```

Then you should have a function to free a hashtable, so you end up using it:

```
if (current_loadfactor > ht->max_loadfactor) {
    hashtab_ptr tempht = ht;
    ht = rehash(ht);
    ht_delete(tempht);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot for the answer, I'd like to try your third solution to create a new htentry_ptr *table.  And also to go backwards through the collision list. Just relinking the entries into the new htentry_ptr *table. Im assuming I can use a sort of loop around for that?

Comment: A loop to fill the htentry_ptr table will have the same problem as the loop to fill the hashtable. You should go for the simple solution first and when it works, you can experiment with a second more efficient rehash function. So I recommend you restart rehashing by just taking out one element of the old table and putting it into a new table (how you generated the first hash table, I suspect there is some kind of add() function in your code).

Comment: If I want to  simply link the entries into the new htentry_ptr *table table and not move them do I need to implement a stack?

Comment: I've edited the Question to show the add/insert function.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You have an array of linked lists. `ht->table` points to the start of the array. If you don't want to move the elements within the linked lists, you can just let the new table point to the old array: `newht->table = ht->table`.

Comment: Ah sorry im really confused, I've edited the question to what I have currently: changed the rehash function to what I think you suggested with your 3rd solution with not creating a newht and just creating  a new htentry_ptr *table.  But now the only problem (i think) is relinking the elements or "move" them.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I want to have a void rehash function though, when moving the entries, I want to move them but I mean: The data to which the entries point are not moved; the entries are simply linked into the new underlying table and not copy anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to show that:

- you only need to reallocate the table[] member, not the envelope
- pointers to pointers can simplify things
- when moving an element from the old table to the new one, you should take care not to damage its next pointer

[Note: I removed the typedefines, because I hate them ...]

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct hashentry {
    struct hashentry *next;
    char *key;
    void *payload;
    };
struct hashtable {
    struct hashentry **table;   /*<< a pointer to array of pointers        */
    unsigned int size;          /*<< current size */
    unsigned int num_entries;   /*<< current number of entries    */
    float max_loadfactor;
    /* unsigned short idx;      the index into the delta array(Quoi?) */
    unsigned int (*hash)(void *, unsigned int); /*<< a pointer to the hash function   */
    int (*cmp)(void *, void *);         /*<< a pointer to the comparison function     */
    };

static void rehash(struct hashtable *ht);
// The rehash function could look like this
static void rehash(struct hashtable *ht)
{
    struct hashentry **newtab;
    struct hashentry **pp, **qq, *this;
    unsigned int newsize, oldidx, newidx;

    newsize = ht->size * 2; /* or something like (max_loadfactor*num_entries), rounded up */
    fprintf(stderr, "new table size %u\n", newsize);
    newtab = malloc(newsize * sizeof *newtab );

    for (newidx=0; newidx < newsize; newidx++) {
        newtab[newidx] = NULL;
        }

    for (oldidx = 0; oldidx < ht->size; oldidx++) {
        for (pp = &ht->table[oldidx]; *pp; ) {
            this = *pp;
            *pp = this->next; /* this is important ! */
            this->next = NULL; /* ... because ... */

            newidx = ht->hash(this->key, newsize);
            for(qq = &newtab[newidx]; *qq; qq = &(*qq)->next) {
                /* You could count the number of "collisions" here */
                }

            *qq = this;
        }
    }
    free(ht->table);
    ht->table = newtab;
    ht->size = newsize;
    /* The rest of the fields does not need to change */
}
```